# A way to know if systemd is indeed the default init

Tags: debian, systemd, grub2, init

I am running Debian testing. I have the following entry in my /etc/default/grub which was probably done a year or two before. Time-stamp says July 2015 but that may be when I made some other changes.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 init=/lib/systemd/systemd"
```

Anyways, IIRC systemd has been the default since Jessie

https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#systemd

So I could just delete it and it reads

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
```

and then update-grub for the action to happen. Is there anything else I should be aware of ?

The ISP's don't have IPV6 hence keeping it disabled for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually yes, but it depends on what you changed on the system.
Do `dpkg -S /sbin/init` to see what your system default is. If it is `systemd-sysv` (the default for clean Jessie upgrade) then systemd is default and you can safely remove it from and systemd will still run after reboot. If it is `sysvinit-core` however, you need to install `systemd-sysv` package if you want systemd to remain default init system.

Comment: I am guessing you are using the -S to simulate the process, clever, now why didn't I think of this.

Comment: Btw the output comes as systemd-sysv so it works.

Comment: @shirish nope, nothing to do with simulating anything.  `dpkg -S` uses `dpkg-query`  to search for filenames in packages.  from `man dpkg` `-S, --search filename-search-pattern...   Search for a filename from installed packages.`  See `man dpkg-query` for more info.  Also, if you have my `dlocate` package installed, running `dlocate -S ' /sbin/init$'` is much faster, especially if you have lots of packages installed.

Comment: ah, now I got it.  /sbin/init is symlinked to whichever init is there. In my case it is symlinked to `[$] ls -lh /sbin/init                                                                                                          
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Jul  8 16:34 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd ` . The other way just lists the package, nifty.

Comment: @shirish yes, in your case, it might be symlink. In other, it might be hard link. In some third case (like mine) it might be just a regular file. `dpkg -S` would still show you in which debian package it belongs on Debian-based systems in most cases, even when determining its "owner" is more complex than reading an symlink destination.

Comment: right, dpkg -S = dpkg Source